# How do I save the strings that starts with "ugle" in a new array after it has been checked in the if statement?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to save the strings that start with "ugle" in the string 'words', but it's annoying the hell out of me.

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

```
string sentence = "Uglen er en rovfugl. Ikke alle rovfugle er ugler. En ugle spiser mus og gylper uglegylp. Alle ugler er gode ugler. " +
                    "De fleste har været små ugleunger med en uglemor og en uglefar. Er ugler uglede i håret? Hvor mange ugler kan bo i en uglerede?";

sentence = sentence.ToLower();
int ugleCount = 0;
Char[] myChars = { ' ', '.', ',', '?' };
string[] words = sentence.Split(myChars);
        
foreach (string x in words)
{
    if (x.StartsWith("ugle"))
    {
        ugleCount++;

    }
}
```

Comment: what _is_ the problem?

Comment: You should include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and a specific problem description stating what you see as wrong about the final result. Don't make us guess what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You are only missing the result for that.

```
    string sentence = "Uglen er en rovfugl. Ikke alle rovfugle er ugler. En ugle spiser mus og gylper uglegylp. Alle ugler er gode ugler. " +
                        "De fleste har været små ugleunger med en uglemor og en uglefar. Er ugler uglede i håret? Hvor mange ugler kan bo i en uglerede?";
    
    sentence = sentence.ToLower();
    Char[] myChars = { ' ', '.', ',', '?' };
    string[] words = sentence.Split(myChars);
    List<string> result = new List<string>();        
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        if (word.StartsWith("ugle"))
        {
            list.Add(word);
        }
    }
```

I suggest you using `word` instead of `x` for readability.

You could also solve this just using Linq.

```
    using System.Linq

    string sentence = "Uglen er en rovfugl. Ikke alle rovfugle er ugler. En ugle spiser mus og gylper uglegylp. Alle ugler er gode ugler. " +
                        "De fleste har været små ugleunger med en uglemor og en uglefar. Er ugler uglede i håret? Hvor mange ugler kan bo i en uglerede?";
    
    sentence = sentence.ToLower();
    Char[] myChars = { ' ', '.', ',', '?' };
    string[] words = sentence.Split(myChars);

    List<string> result =  words.Where(word => word.StartsWith("ugle")).ToList();
```

In both cases you don't need an `ugleCount`.

In case you need to mandatory keep using `words[]` for the result just change on the second example to:

```
words = words.Where(word => word.StartsWith("ugle")).ToArray();
```